# Deduplicate lead in suguacrm 6.4.4

Tags: java, php, sugarcrm

I'm running Sugar CE version 6.4.4 and I accidentally forgot to check for duplicate contacts, email addresses.Is there any way to merge multiple contacts at once rather than doing it manually one at a time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Rajkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SugarCRM knowledge base article....

http://support.sugarcrm.com/03_Training/01_How_Do_I/10_Work_with_Records/039_Merge_Duplicate_Records